# Python ZipFile empties file in root folder

Tags: python, file, recursion, directory, zip

I am having issues with zipping a folder. Everything goes fine, all files that are in directories get zipped just fine. But there needs to be a version file in the root of the zip file, and when I zip it, and then unzip, the file is empty, 0 bytes.

This is the code I am using in Python to zip a directory recursively:

```
from contextlib import closing
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED   

def zipdir(self, basedir, archive_name):
    """Zip a directory."""
    assert os.path.isdir(basedir)
    with closing(ZipFile(archive_name, "w", ZIP_DEFLATED)) as z:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
            for fn in files:
                filepath = os.path.join(root, fn)
                zfn = filepath[len(basedir) + len(os.sep):]
                z.write(filepath, zfn)
```

The dir structure is as follows:

```
/root
   version.file
   /somedir
      file1
      file2
      file3
   /anotherdir
      file1
      file2
      file3
   /etcdir
      file1
      file2
      file3
```

When I zip root, the version.file is empty (e.g. 0 bytes), and I have no idea why.

Regards

Comment: @ZevAverbach could you elaborate? The absfn and zfn seem to be correct. e.g. the zfn of the version.file is "version.file". where should your suggestion go?

Comment: sorry, that wasn't the issue after all.  I'm not able to replicate this problem: Files in the root dir are decompressing as the proper filesize...